# I have a created my main (index.jsp) page for my website

Tags: jsp

I have a created my main (index.jsp) page for my website which will load a drop down selection control with data from DB using embedded jsp.

My ?:  Will the jsp be run/loaded each time the page loads (i.e. with a "Return to Main Page" from another web page) or will the results from previous call to jsp ( in cache) be used?

I would like page to load as fast as possible.

Thank you for you help,
Greg

Comment: Yes, if you don't have a session/application-scope with some caching, all actions of your index.jsp must be done, every time index.jsp is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, yes, index.jsp will execute all the code in the JSP file every time a user follows a link that says `Return to Main Page`.

If you want to optimise load times I suggest you use `cookies` (for non-secure information **ONLY**) or `sessions`. While doing this ensure that you do not allow the index.jsp to reload everything and extract the information from the DB again (otherwise you're defeating the purpose of a session!) You may do something like this:

```
<%
    if (session != null) {
%>

<!-- insert code here to load page using information stored in session -->

<%
    } else {
%>

<!-- insert your existing code here, to load the index.jsp page fresh, as there is an absence of session -->

<%
    }
%>
```

Below are useful pages to help you get started on storing information in `cookies` and `sessions`.

[Cookies](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_cookies_handling.htm)

[Sessions](http://www.jsptut.com/sessions.jsp)

(Read everything!)

Otherwise, if you need to just pass information between a few pages (e.g. from a page with contents to the main index page) hidden form fields can be used to pass information as a makeshift `"session"`, like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="session" value="<%= some_value %>">
```

Hope this helps, cheers!

EDIT: Added more information on how to load the JSP page with and without sessions.

Comment: clamismagic,  Thank you. I need to brush up on session's and implement into my program.

Comment: Thanks! If I have helped you today, accepting my answer would be the best way to say thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> Will the jsp be run/loaded each time the page loads (i.e. with a "Return to Main Page" from another web page) or will the results from previous call to jsp ( in cache) be used?

It depends.

You can use [cache control headers](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) to tell the browser to cache the result.

You can use a [server side cache such as Varnish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varnish_(software)) to cache the results on your server so that any client connecting can have a cached version.

Or you can let the file be requested and rerun the Java code each time.